# Склоняется ли слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В одной документальной передаче, говоря об эволюции человека, название Homo sapiens склоняли по падежам (Хомо сапиенсу, Хомо сапиенса - и т.д.). Как мне это резануло слух. Правильно ли они говорили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Толковый словарь Ефремовой нам авторитетно заявляет, что *"гомо сапиенс"* - несконяемое существительное ([пруф](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274176/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE)). Поэтому в той документальной передаче говорили неправильно.